# Where can I convert my WLMP into MP4 online?

Tags: web-apps, media-converter

Where can I convert my WLMP into MP4 online? Is it possible? By google I didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

You can try here, it says it does , but I have not tried it

[Online-Convert to MP4](https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4)

and the main site can convert alot of files audio, video, images, etc

[Online-Convert](https://www.online-convert.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[This site](https://videoconverter.iskysoft.com/convert-mp4/convert-wlmp-to-mp4.html) says Windows Movie Maker can open and export it to mp4. Some other software I know that can convert video files are

- [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)
- [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/)
- [Adobe Media Encoder](https://www.adobe.com/products/media-encoder.html)

Comment: It's not an online converter.  You should download it to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to convert wlmp file to mp4 online. This is because wlmp is not media format... Others' suggestion definitely won't work.

Comment: A quick googling showed that it looks like one. It is some windows movie maker project file. I think it is possible that it contains only references to other media files.

Comment: Right. "What a WLM file records are the location information for the entire media component of a video, and all the works that have been done on the timeline." So, it's only possible to be recognizable in Windows Movie Maker.